# DTO to existing object without loosing rest of existing object data

Tags: c#, automapper, dto

Consider :

```
class OriginalContact
{
    public int Id{set;get;}
    public string Name{set;get;}
    public string CustomerCode{set;get;}
}

class DTOContact
{
    public int Id{set;get;}
    public string Name{set;get;}
}

OriginalContact originalContact = new OriginalContact
{
    CustomerCode="123";
}

DTOContact dtoContact= new DTOContact
{
    Id=1,
    Name="David"
}

Mapper.Map(dtoContact, originalContact);
```

After this mapping i lose **CustomerCode** value

Is there any way to map while keeping original values ?

Comment: Can you show your create map configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to 'ignore' the destination value in your create map configuration:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<DTOContact,OriginalContact>()
  .ForMember(dest => dest.CustomerCode, options => options.Ignore());
```

Comment: thank you sir. but is there any easy way than this ? if my original object had too many other properties which was not included on DTO object, that would be painful. what about ValueInjecter ?